# Explode column with array of arrays - PySpark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

**I have a column with data like this:**

```
[[[-77.1082606, 38.935738]] ,Point]
```

**I want it split out like:**

```
  column 1          column 2        column 3
 -77.1082606      38.935738           Point
```

How is that possible using PySpark, or alternatively Scala (Databricks 3.0)? I know how to explode columns but not split up these structs. Thanks!!!

**EDIT: Here is the schema of the column:**

```
|-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = false
```

Comment: What's the type? `array<array<>>`? Please post result of `printSchema`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()` to get rid of the square brackets, and then `split()` the resulting string by the comma into separate columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, split, col

df.select(regexp_replace(df.geometry.coordinates, "[\[\]]", "").alias("coordinates"),
          df.geometry.type.alias("col3")) \
  .withColumn("arr", split(col("coordinates"), "\\,")) \
  .select(col("arr")[0].alias("col1"),
          col("arr")[1].alias("col2"),
         "col3") \
  .drop("arr") \
  .show(truncate = False)
+-----------+----------+-----+
|col1       |col2      |col3 |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|-77.1082606| 38.935738|Point|
+-----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: I couldn't recall the syntax - you were faster :D +1 and I suggest @AshleyO to also give +1 and accept :)

Comment: I should have been more clear, the data is all in one struct. I've edited to display the information more clearly. I'm testing to see if this concept can help though

Comment: so you have `["[[-77.1082606, 38.935738]]" ,"Point"] ` ?

Comment: Correct. All in one column